# Method not found: 'Void Lucene.Net.Store.Azure.AzureDirectory..ctor(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount, System.String)'

Tags: azure, lucene.net

I have the following solution deployed to Azure. It basically is a website to add and edit user information. It uses a Azure table storage for data access.

Recently I started adding search functionality using Lucene.net and more specifcally Lucene.Net.Store.Azure.

```
<package id="Lucene.Net.Store.Azure" version="3.0.5553.21100" targetFramework="net451" />
```

I have developed it locally against an existing Azure storage container and it works. I'm able to build the index and  can query it.

I just published the new version to Azure, and it behaves differently from the local code. I now get a runtime error that it can't find a method, more specifically the constructor.

```
Method not found: 'Void Lucene.Net.Store.Azure.AzureDirectory..ctor(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount, System.String)'
```

It is addressed (some code omitted for brevity), like this.

```
private AzureDirectory _azureDirectory;
CloudStorageAccount cloudAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(settings.Endpoint);

_azureDirectory = new AzureDirectory(cloudAccount, "storagename");
```

it's from this nuget https://azuredirectory.codeplex.com/

Maybe someone can pinpoint me in the right direction.

Basically what is happening is that the version of Lucene.net.Store.Azure used by Azure is a different version than I'm using locally? Is this assumption correct, and how can I check the Azure version?

Is this because of the difference in .Net framework of the Azure server and my local development?

How can this be fixed?

any help appreciated

Comment: Can you check if the DLL is copied properly when deployed to Azure?

Comment: Yeah it's deployed alright.

Comment: Could it be that the problem is that I'm on a free MDSN azure subscription, that only let's you run 32 bit mode?